# Image in SVG not displayed in README.md GitHub

Tags: image, github, svg, markdown, readme

i'm making a markdown file in which is present an SVG.
Inside this SVG i wanna include an image, but it doesn't work.
Whenever i remove the image, it works fine.
You got any idea? Thank you so much in advance!

This is the svg code:

```
   <svg fill="none" viewBox="0 0 508 125" width="800" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <div class="dialogue-card" id="dialogue-box">
            <image xlink:href="https://github.com/Goth-Rei-Codes/goth-rei-codes/blob/main/Images/propic.png" />
            <div class="propic-container">
                <div class="name-container">
                    <div class="dialogue-text">
                        <p>Welcome to my profile!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="arrow-down" id="next-dialogue"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</foreignObject></svg>
```

[image]

Comment: any tip about how to do that?

Comment: i got no idea what i have to insert in the tag to be honest

Comment: Search for the correct Github link notation; the URI you use does **not** display an image, it is the link to a Repo file. You want the _**raw**_ link

Comment: i've found the raw link but still unable to load it, check this line of code please <image xlink:href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Goth-Rei-Codes/goth-rei-codes/main/Images/propic.png" />